# Is the apache ab tool sufficient enough for benchmark testing a Magento server?

Tags: benchmark

I'm working to improve the load time of my Magento installation but obviously I need something accurate to show me what actually works and doesn't work.

I started using the ApacheBench *ab* tool and running the server without any cache, with cache and a FPC show the improvements I was expecting.

I don't know that the LestiFPC is the best module available, while it works well I'm sure load times can be better. None of the paid FPC's have run any testing against each other or have any hard numbers to backup their claims so I need something indisputable that is recognized.

Is the ApacheBench tool sufficient to test load times of a Magento installation or are there other more recognized tools that would be better suited for this purpose?

Comment: the only good cache is varnish, apache ab it does not show you anything sane. and you have to test your checkout process mostly, and overall user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823964/how-accurate-is-testing-with-siege-and-ab) Stack Overflow question?

The [article](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/why-siege-isnt-an-accurate-test-tool-for-magento-performance/) it links to raises a number of good points, although it is referencing siege, the same problems will apply to ab.

The biggest problem for me is your not going to be behaving like a real user. When a real user browses a magento site they will be hitting many different urls, some of these will have dynamic queries passed through the url which will be missing your caching layer. Testing a pre defined list of urls is simply not going to be using your server resources like a real user would.

In saying that if you simply want compare the difference between a single cached and non cached page, then it would probably be ok.